# what is wrong with in docker-compose.override.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Good day,

I am new to docker.

What is wrong with the following docker-compose.override.yml

```
services:
  webapplication_oauth_server:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "6100:80"
      - "16100:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro

  webapplication_client:
      environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "6101:80"
      - "16101:443"
```

Comment: Here docker-compose.yml
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication_oauth_server:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapplicationoauthserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApplication_OAuth_Server/Dockerfile

  webapplication_client:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapplicationclient
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApplication_Client/Dockerfile

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: Description does not give me specific error explanation. It just says that error in line 19
which is 
`ports:
      - "6101:80"
      - "16101:443"`

Comment: if I use  docker-compose ps in powershell

**ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in ".\docker-compose.override.yml", line 4, column 3
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in ".\docker-compose.override.yml", line 19, column 5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found solution. from other post I found that there is website http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

It can help parse and check if there is error. I experimented and found that I need to add 2 spaces before last ports tag.
This is old version with error:

```
      environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "6101:80"
      - "16101:443"
```

and here correct version:

```
      environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      ports:
      - "6101:80"
      - "16101:443"
```